# localstorage cart returning null value

Tags: duplicates, addition, cart

Hey Everyone for some reason my local storage cart is coming up null, and undefined in the console, I don't know what happened but it was working before. when I parse the cart it comes up as null. The products array is working correctly it logs all the products but when I try to push to the cart it comes up as null. Can someone please please help me, I am stuck on this and I have been at it for a long while. Please help I would really appreciate it.

Javascript

```
fetch('/javascripts/products.json').then((response) => response.json())
.then((data) => {
    localStorage.setItem('products', JSON.stringify(data))
    if(!localStorage.getItem('cart')) {
        localStorage.setItem('cart', '[]')
}
})


///setting up global variables so can access inside functions
let products = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('products'));
console.log(products)
let cart = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('cart'));

const addBtns = document.getElementsByClassName('shop-item-button');

for (let i = 0; i < addBtns.length; i++) {
        let button = addBtns[i];

button.addEventListener('click', addItem)
}

 function addItem(event, productId) {
    // console.log(event.target)
    const button = event.target
    const shopItem = button.parentElement.parentElement;
    // console.log(event.target.dataset.productSku)
    // console.log(shopItem);
    const title = shopItem.getElementsByClassName('shop-item-title')[0].innerText;
const image = shopItem.getElementsByClassName('shop-item-image')[0].src;
    const price = shopItem.getElementsByClassName('shop-item-price')[0].innerText;
console.log(title, image, price);

let product = products.find((product) => {
    product.name = title;
    product.image = image;
    product.price = price;
return product.id === productId;
})

if (cart.length >= 0) {
console.log(cart)
    cart.push(product);
} else {
    let res = cart.find(element => element.id == productId)
    if (res === undefined) {
        cart.push(product);
}
}
localStorage.setItem('cart', JSON.stringify(cart))
// console.log(cart)
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="shop-items">
          <div class="shop-item">
            <span class="shop-item-title">Black Mug</span>
            <img class="blackMug Mugs shop-item-image" src="/assets/images/IMG_0444.jpeg" alt="">
            <div class="cart-item-details">
              <p>Deutschland Autohaus premier coffee mug (Black)</p>
              <span class="shop-item-price">$30</span>
              <button class="cartBTN1 btn btn-primary shop-item-button" data-product-sku="blackmug">Add to cart</button>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="shop-item">
            <span class="shop-item-title">Red Mug</span>
            <img class="redMug Mugs shop-item-image" src="/assets/images/IMG_0442.jpeg" alt="">
            <div class="cart-item-details">
              <p>Deutschland Autohaus premier coffee mug (Red)</p>
              <span class="shop-item-price">$30</span>
              <button class="cartBTN2 btn btn-primary shop-item-button">Add to cart</button>
            </div>
           </div>
           <div class="shop-item">
                <span class="shop-item-title">Grey Sweatshirt</span>
                <img class="greySweater shop-item-image" src="/assets/images/greysweater.jpg" alt="">
                <div class="cart-item-details">
                  <p>Deutschland Autohaus premier sweetshirt (Grey)</p>
                  <span class="shop-item-price">$50</span>
                  <button class="cartBTN btn btn-primary shop-item-button">Add to cart</button>
                </div>
           </div>
           <div class="shop-item">
              <span class="shop-item-title">Black Sweatshirt</span>
              <img class="blackSweater shop-item-image" src="/assets/images/blacksweater.jpg" alt="">
              <div class="cart-item-details">
                  <p>Deutschland Autohaus premier sweetshirt (Black)</p>
                  <span class="shop-item-price">$45</span>
                  <button class="cartBTN btn btn-primary shop-item-button">Add to cart</button>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="shop-item">
                <span class="shop-item-title">Blue Sweatershirt</span>
                <img class="blueSweater shop-item-image" src="/assets/images/bluesweater.jpg" alt="">
              <div class="cart-item-details">
                  <p>Deutschland Autohaus premier sweetshirt (Blue)</p>
                  <span class="shop-item-price">$50</span>
                  <button class="cartBTN btn btn-primary shop-item-button">Add to cart</button>
              </div>
            </div>
            </div>
```